# instagram font awesome tooltip can't find

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Is there a

```
class="social-twitter tooltips"
```

for instagram in font awesome??

I need font awesome tooltip class to work with instagram. Basically, I need the instagram icon to appear in the footer when I hover over it.

It works for facebook, twitter, etc. but not for instagram.
Below is the code for twitter and facebook where it works. It does not work for instagram (example at end of page).

```
<li class="social-twitter tooltips" data-original-title="Twitter"
data-placement="bottom">
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/opensponsorship" target=
    "_blank">Twitter</a>
</li>

<li class="social-facebook tooltips" data-original-title="Facebook"
data-placement="bottom">
    <a data-original-title="Facebook" href=
    "http://facebook.com/opensponsorship" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
</li>

<!-- DOES NOT WORK FOR INSTAGRAM! -->

<li class="social-instagram tooltips" data-original-title="Instagram"
data-placement="bottom">
    <a data-original-title="Instagram" href=
    "http://instagram.com/opensponsorship" target=
    "_blank">Instagram</a>
</li>
```

Comment: It's not by default,  there's an add on though...   http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS classes appear to be from another source as far as I can tell. You have two options available from Font Awesome and Bootstrap.

### [Font Awesome Social Icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)

```
<i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
```

[image: Font Awesome example]

### [Social Buttons for Bootstrap](http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/)

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-instagram" 
   onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'btn-social', 'click', 'btn-instagram']);">
    <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i> Sign in with Instagram
</a>
```

[image: Bootstrap example]